# PHP Date function not working properly

Tags: php, date, datetime

Why is my PHP code giving me the wrong result the following code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('d-m-Y');
```

Is working and producing:

```
30-01-2013
```

However this code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime("+1 month"));
```

Is producing this date:

```
02-03-2013
```

Instead of:

```
28-02-2013
```

However I only need the month number.

Comment: The result is fine. What did you expect to see?

Comment: this infamous bug gets reported at the end of every month because people do not understand how relative dates work. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=22486

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by using

```
http://derickrethans.nl/obtaining-the-next-month-in-php.html
```

Code:

```
echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime("first day of next month"));
```

As I only needed the month number.

Answer (score 7):

It actually is correct.

Today is `30-01`. +1 month should be `30-02`. This date does not exist so it turns to `02-03` (28-02 + 2 days)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is explained by a PHP developer [here](http://derickrethans.nl/obtaining-the-next-month-in-php.html). There are workarounds you can use, but you will have to explain the logic by which you arrive at the conclusion that Jan 31 + 1 month is Feb 02.

Answer (score 0):

Its because febuary have only 28 days. The strtotime +1 Month is adding 30 days, try to use the DateTime class instead: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

Check out ,

```
<?php   
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    //Current date
    $date= date("Y-m-d");

    // Timestamp of new date after adding 1 month
    $timestamp= strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . "+1 month");

    //Converting timestamp of new date to readable date.
    $newdate= date("Y-m-d",$timestamp);
?>
```